# Integrating VUE to the exsiting mvc razer page application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, vue.js, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an existing MVC razor page application. From the home page that is implemented in MVC razer page when I click on login button other pages I need to implement in the VUE JS . How can do that ? How do I put link to the vuejs component.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want the login button can link to a vue component, it should be in a Vue Instance, then use [vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html) to do the redirection.

But if you want to have a single page application, and mixing asp.net mvc views with vue.js is not a good idea. Eventually, you will face many problems. It could be better implement web api services with dotnet core and vue as the client